# css text-indent equivalent on the right side

Tags: css

I have right-side aligned text and I want it to push it a little bit left like you do with text-indent bur on the right side. Any solution with that?
I've been trying with margin, but IE9 doubles the margin on the first menu item (?).

Heres the css:

```
h99
{ padding: 0px;
    font-family: lucida, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#menublock
{ width: 230px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

ul
{ list-style-type: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul a:link, ul a:visited
{ display: block;
  width: 210px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
}

ul a:hover, .selected
{ background: #484848 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

The menu is a simply horizontal one.

Comment: Yes, it's a known bug in IE6 [Read more](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html). Not sure why you should care though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is none, unfortunately there is no text outdent in css, hower, you could use text direction `direction:rtl;` for some short texts, in that way indent will appear on the other side.

Comment: @KLL1K3R It feels like making text RTL is going to give you as many issues as it solves. Keep in mind that if you have something like `<p>Foo bar:</p>` that you give a style of RTL, you'll end up with **":Foo bar"**

Comment: Seconding what @anotherdave says.  By the time you get this worked out, you could redesign the entire layout.

Answer (score 10):

Simple solution is to apply a "before" CSS style to your text element which negates all side effects of `direction: rtl;`

```
&:before {
      content: ' ';
      width: 100px;
      float: right;
      height: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! What about `height: 1em;`?

Comment: Smart solution! You can still using text-indent on left side if you need.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following

```
text-indent: 60px;
direction: rtl;
text-align: left;
```

**f.ardelian** pointed out: Punctuation will appear at the beginning of the line so abc. will appear .abc

Comment: **Warning:** Punctuation will appear at the beginning of the line so `abc.` will appear `.abc`

Answer (score 3):

What I did and worked for me was this:

```
text-indent: 20px;
padding-right: 40px;
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS only solution, does not mess with text direction (SEO and translation friendly?), no floats, no additional elements, width of post-indent is easy to modify:

```
&::after {
    content: "\0000a0";
    height: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Works on Firefox, but not Safari or Chrome.

Comment: I have developed this workaround specifically using Chrome, tested it once again on Safari moments ago - works like a charm so there must be something you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your code however a solution to your problem with old browsers is to include an empty span and apply a width:

```
<style>
span.right-adjust {
  display:inline-block;
  width:5px;
}
</style>

<div>Your text here<span class="right-adjust"></span></div>
```

It is hard to tell what you want without providing us with code. You could also apply a float:right;

There are many ways to solve issues with old browsers and CSS.

Hope this helps