# How to indent text from the right side?

Tags: html, css

Consider this example:

[image]

How to indent text from the right side ? As seen from the example, this is indented from the left side, but how to make it opposite without affecting any other elements ?

I tried to play with `text-indent`, but could not figure it out.

I also refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909947/css-text-indent-equivalent-on-the-right-side), but also could not get it working.

I managed to do it with `float: right` and `padding`, but they become block elements in that case, which should not happen.

[image]

`text-align` does this, but it moves all of it to the right side. I want to keep it on the left, but with reverse alingment. It also should not affect anything on the right or left side of it.

Comment: i might have misunderstood you, but doesn't text-align do that to you? you could set text-align:left or right, while direction: ltr

Comment: that doesn't look indented.. just looks like left-aligned text ...

Comment: check out the edit

Comment: try `text-align: right` (without float etc.)

Comment: Can you supply the html and css you currently have?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/415jy9p6/

Comment: Can you post the tags that you are using, include the parent element as well with their css properties. for example text aling wont work if you are using span.

https://jsfiddle.net/juanpa/av9y35sd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you want the text to be right-aligned with some padding so it's not right up against the side of the box.

```css
p {
  text-align:right;
  padding-right: 5em;
}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
<p>test test</p>
<p>somethin grandom</p>
<p>test again</p>
<p>this is the last test</p>
```

An alternative is to use `direction`:

```css
p {
  direction:rtl;
  text-indent: 5em
}
```

```html
<p>test</p>
<p>test test</p>
<p>somethin grandom</p>
<p>test again</p>
<p>this is the last test</p>
```

Comment: Something like that, yes. It's hard to catch up all the answers, but I think I've what I've needed. Thanks to all

Comment: Note that `direction: rtl;` can produce unwanted side effects with punctuation etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: inline-block` with text-align. It will expand the container just enough and will not change the display to block:

```css
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  test<br>
  test test test<br>
  test test
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the element `inline-block` and then use `text-align`:

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>some text text and more</p>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Or use `float:left` and clear float after if you want to have a line break after:

```css
.text {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>some text text and more</p>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:left;">
 lorem ipsume dolret lorem ipsume dolret lorem ipsume dolret lorem ipsume dolret lorem ipsume dolret lorem ipsume dolret lorem ipsume dolret
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using text direction `direction:rtl;`, and then applying the indentation. This way your text will appear to be indented from the right.

Answer (score -4):

Add `padding-right: 20px;` to the stylesheet. Of course you can change the value.

Comment: that's not valid css...

Comment: and it affects everything around it

Comment: I am from phone. Already edited my answer.